# How to keep adding values to a key that already exists, when the values are in an ArrayList? Input is coming in from a scanner to create a TreeMap

Tags: java, list, dictionary, multimap

I am trying to receive input from a user where each line must consist of some text (a key), followed by a tab character, followed by a `double` literal (a value), followed by a newline.

If the user is allowed to keep entering the same key, followed by `/t`, then a different value and `/n`, how can I write a program that keeps adding the value to the same key in a tree map?

Each key has an `ArrayList`, which is where I get stuck because I don't know how to keep adding to an array list for different lines/keys.

This is what I have so far:

```
    TreeMap<String, ArrayList<Double>> categoryMap = new TreeMap<>();

    Double val = 0.0;
    String inputKey = "";

    System.out.println("Welcome, please enter text");
    Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);
    dataSource = scn;

    try
    {
        // adds all words of input to a string array
        while (dataSource.hasNextLine())
        {
            ArrayList<Double> valueMap = new ArrayList<>();
            inputKey = dataSource.next();

            val = dataSource.nextDouble();
            valueMap.add(val);

            if (categoryMap.get(inputKey) == null)
            {
                categoryMap.put(inputKey, valueMap);
            }
            else
            {
                categoryMap.put(inputKey, valueMap);
            }

            dataSource.nextLine();
        }
    }
    // Exception if no lines detected and shows message
    catch (IllegalArgumentException lineExcpt)
    {
        System.out.println("No lines have been input: " + lineExcpt.getMessage());
    }
    finally
    {
        scn.close();
    }

    return categoryMap;
```

I'm extremely new to java with only about a month of experience.

Comment: I'm trying to get input as described above, and put the information in a TreeMap called categoryMap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the logic inside your `while` loop needs some modification. Currently you are overriding the value list with a new one each time.

Here is what you have on paper:

- If the key does not exist, create a new list with the given `double` and use it as the value.
- Else, get the (already existing) list and add the `double` to it.

In code, we just need to modify what you did:

```
String inputKey = dataSource.next();
double val = dataSource.nextDouble();
List<Double> list = categoryMap.get(inputKey);

if (list == null)                    // If the key does not exist
{
    list  = new ArrayList<>();       // create a new list
    list.add(val);                   // with the given double
    categoryMap.put(inputKey, list); // and use it as the value
}
else                                 // Else
{
    list.add(val)                    // (got the list already) add the double to it
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use Java 8, maps have the `computeIfAbsent` method.

```
List<Double> addTo = map.computeIfAbsent(key, ArrayList::new);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should get the arraylist for that key from the map and add the value there, something like `categoryMap.get (inputKey).add(val)` inside your else, code could be improved, but I'm using a phome now...